# How to automatically create whole path when creating new file using vim?

Tags: linux, vim, gnu

To open new files while in vim I usually do the following:

```
:tabe my_newfile
```

However, say I want to open a new file in a NEW directory, like so:

```
:tabe newdir/my_newfile
```

leads to the error

```
"newdir/my_newfile" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Is there a smooth way to create the newdir automatically?

Comment: How often to you misspell a directory name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292733/vim-creating-parent-directories-on-save

Comment: @AaronDigulla never: I use vim's (awesome) tab completion: `:tabed path/**/stylesheets/<Tab><Tab>newdir/mynewfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the plugin [auto_mkdir](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3352). It sounds exactly what you are searching for.

PS: I don't have used it, and I will not (due to the comment of @Aaron_Digulla

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this workaround outside of vim: I've created a shell script `vim` in `$HOME/bin` which makes backup of every file that I edit in folder `$HOME/.vimback/...path.../file`.

In a similar way, you could create a similar script that runs

```
for f in "$@" ; do
    mkdir -p $(dirname "$f")
done

/usr/bin/$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

But I'd suggest to ask whether the directories should be created to avoid accidentally creating directories because of typos.