# How to setup a file pattern for autocmd to not match the command line buffer?

Tags: vim, autocmd

I have an au command to check if a file had been changed:

```
autocmd CursorHold * checktime
```

But when I launch a command line window with `q:` or with `q/` than I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing CursorHold Auto commands for "*":
E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits: checktime
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My question is, is it possible to set up the autocmd's pattern to exclude command line buffers and other readonly buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest fix is to just silence the errors:

```
autocmd CursorHold * silent! checktime
```

Alternatively, you could also wrap this in `try`...`catch /:E11:/`. Or, you could attempt to check for the command-line window:

```
autocmd CursorHold * if expand('%') !=# '[Command Line]' | checktime | endif
```

Comment: You can also check to make sure `'buftype'` is empty. Here is the answer with a different goal but similar needs: [Vim: Creating parent directories on save](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4294176/438329)