# How do I run an autocommand on every filetype but one?

Tags: vim, autocommand

I have my vim set up to save files whenever I change buffers and on checktime. The problem is that I use Netrw and end up saving Netrw buffers. Can I run an autocommand on every type of file except netrw?

Comment: This might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496778/vim-run-autocmd-on-all-filetypes-except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `:if` in your `autocmd` to guard against netrw files. e.g.

```
autocmd FileType * if &ft != 'netrw' | echo "do something" | endif
```

However this still isn't quite right. You have stopped from saving netrw buffers, but there are other buffers that shouldn't be saved. I would suggest checking `'buftype'` and looking for files that start with a protocol e.g. `foo://`.

Here is an [example of auto creating intermediary directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292733/vim-creating-parent-directories-on-save) using such an approach:

```
" create parent directories
" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292733/vim-creating-parent-directories-on-save
function! s:MkNonExDir(file, buf)
    if empty(getbufvar(a:buf, '&buftype')) && a:file!~#'\v^\w+\:\/'
        let dir=fnamemodify(a:file, ':h')
        if !isdirectory(dir)
            call mkdir(dir, 'p')
        endif
    endif
endfunction
augroup BWCCreateDir
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre * :call s:MkNonExDir(expand('<afile>'), +expand('<abuf>'))
augroup END
```